# Push a block of information to an array X times based on an external variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am modding a game where some JavaScript is used to push AIs into game slots. For game reasons I want to create multiple entries within the slots array based on an external variable.

I don't really know JavaScript and so have been fumbling my way through my modding up till this point so this is likely simple but I don't understand the terms I should be Googling.

This is the vanilla code:

```
armies.push({
  slots: [{
    ai: true,
    name: ai.name,
    commander: fixupCommander(ai.commander)
  }],
  color: ai.color,
  econ_rate: ai.econ_rate,
  personality: ai.personality,
  spec_tag: '.ai',
  alliance_group: 2
});
```

And I'm looking to end up with the slots part looking something like:

```
  slots: [{
    ai: true,
    name: ai.name,
    commander: fixupCommander(ai.commander)
  },
  {
    ai: true,
    name: ai.name,
    commander: fixupCommander(ai.commander)
  },
  {
```

Where the number of copies of that block is determined by the external variable e.g. ai.copies = 3, make 3 blocks within slots.

The engine supports up to ECMAScript 5, or whatever Chromium 28 was capable of.

Comment: First create the slots with a simple *for*-loop. Pushing the values into an array variable. Then use that variable as value for `slots`. You could also do `slots = new Array(ai.copies).fill({ ... })`

Comment: Keep in mind that the constructor argument of array must be an integer, otherwise a normal array is created of size 1 containing the item provided in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do it is the iterative way by simply using a for loop to execute `ai.copies` times and insert a copy each time:

```
var slotsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ai.copies; i++) {
    slotsArray.push({
        ai: true,
        name: ai.name,
        commander: fixupCommander(ai.commander)
    });
}

armies.push({
  slots: slotsArray,
  color: ai.color,
  econ_rate: ai.econ_rate,
  personality: ai.personality,
  spec_tag: '.ai',
  alliance_group: 2
});
```

there are some other ways like using the functional paradigm, but this would do it

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the help! As a small follow-up, I want to default the loop to 1 unless it finds ai.copies holding a value. To do this I'm assuming the best way is `var count = ai.copies || 1;` and then use count in place of ai.copies in the loop?

Comment: I was also surprised that the closing curly brace of the loop didn't require either a semicolon or comma after it to separate it from armies.push, and in face the editor complained if I used either. Can you recommend a good source on understanding why that is and when to use what?

Comment: @Quitch in general in JS, semicolons aren't mandatory except when you wanna separate multiple  things (statements..) on a single line like function () {console.log("semicolon needed"); return 0}. But there are some blocks that don't take semicolons: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion/

Comment: In order to default it to 1, yes you can do like you said